# How to figure out error in Oracle ADF Mobile application

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

As I have tried with sample application project from Oracle ADF-Mobile tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/BuildingMobileApps/ADFMobileTutorial_2.html

but I facing with some error pop-up that show within application [image]

How to debug or trace an error that default pop-up ? since I think that maybe error with Web Service Calling.

Answer (score 0):

Debug your application.
See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35521_01/doc.111230/e24475/debugging.htm

Or check your system.log but I don't recommend that because you only get very limited information.